# Zen nth element

Tags: emmet

I've been using zen coding and I love it. There's just one thing I can't figure out how to do (or if it's even possible.)

Say I typed:

`ul#navigation>li*3`

Which would output:

`<ul id="navigation">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>`

How would I apply a class to a specific numbered element? Such as add a class called 'hello' to the second `<li>?`

Answer (score 3):

You can‘t apply specific class for repeating element in this case.

However, you can insert specific class name (or any other attribute) by *wrapping text with abbreviation*. For example, you can wrap this text:

```
one
two
three
```

with the following abbreviation: `ul#navigation>li[class=$#]*`. It will produce the following output:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="two"></li>
    <li class="three"></li>
</ul>
```

Read more on https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/wiki/Release-Notes